# Laravel NotFoundHttpException when loading asset file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having a weird issue on Laravel 5.2 when loading an asset file (image). When I specify the absolute path to the image on the browser I receive an error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

The permissions are set and the .htaccess file is the standard one. When I access that images files folder all the files appear.

Example:

```
domain.com/images/                    : this lists all the images in the folder

domain.com/images/image.png           : I get the NotFoundHttpException
```

Any issues where the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

just figured out the issue, it was a user permissions issue:

`chown -R user:usergroup folder/*` fixed it